# Using Create-React-App, how can you customize the META tags per URL?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm currently using create-react-app for my application. This uses hardcoded meta-tags in the public/index.html file like so:

```
<title>XXXX</title>
<meta name="description" content="XXXXX" />
<meta property="og:title" content="XXXXXXX">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://xxx">
```

The problem with this is, the meta tags are hard coded for all pages... How can you dynamically override these meta tags on different urls in the app. For example, for a user profile page like so:

```
myapp.com/profiles/usernameX
```

How can I have that URL return specific meta tags?

Comment: Something like this should work `document.querySelectorAll('meta[name="description"]').setAttribute('content', content);`. This works for anything that runs Javascript on your page. For anything else (old search engines maybe), you would need to do it with server side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're looking for is [`react-helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/), a document head manager for React. `react-helmet` can manage any changes to the document head. For example, you may put `meta` tags in your `index.html`, but as soon as a React component renders with different `meta` tags in its `<Helmet>` component (how `react-helmet` manages head) the `meta` tags from the `index.html` will be overridden. This overriding also happens between different React components, with child components taking precedence.

A good example of `react-helmet` is on *The Stuyvesant Spectator's* website: https://stuyspec.com (notice how the `<title>` changes depending on the page/article you're on).

If you want server-side action, you can use [Gatsby](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby). Gatsby is a static site generator for React, and it has a react-helmet package that goes along with it ([`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet)).

Comment: thanks but react-helmet won't work with create-react-app for the og meta tag requirement because it needs to happen on server-side requests when fb, linkedin, twitter etc curl the URL to get the meta tags. I believe this needs to happen on the server

Comment: understood. i added an edit for server-side requests